# Solaris - search files in a specified directory

Tags: shell, unix, find, command

I'm trying to get my `find` command work, but I can't. 
I'm trying to find for executable by the user files ONLY in given directory excluding it's subdirectories. 
The problem is I don't have `-maxdepth`, `-path`, `-regex` keys in my `find` command, so I'm trying to do it with `-prune` option.
I found `find /dev \( ! -name /dev -prune \) -type f -print` solution in another similar question on Stackoverflow, but it does't work either.
Currently my command looks like this 
`find -- "$path" \( ! -name "$path" -prune \) -type f -perm -u=x -print`
`"$path` can be both - absolute or relative path

Comment: wondering what system has a find without `-maxdepth`.

Comment: @jm666, Solaris 8 for one.

Comment: @glennjackman thanx, because i tried a `find` on my satellite receiver (crumpled busybox) and it knows maxdepth :) Strange Solaris. ;)

Comment: what about problem solutions?:)

Comment: What shell are you using, i.e. why do you need `find`? Something like `for f in "$path"/*; do [[ -f "$f" ]] && [[ $(stat -c %a "$f") =~ ^[1357] ]] && echo "$f"; done`

Answer (score 0):

Can you bypass `find`?

`ls -la "$path"| awk '^/-[r-][w-]x/ {print $9}'`

That is, list files in long listing, only keep those lines with the required permissions and print the filename.

Comment: Parsing `ls` is usually bad, though might be the way to go if the particular version of `solaris` doesn't have `stat`. Not sure your `awk` is going to work, might try something like `ls -la | grep -P '^-[r-][w-]x'` instead

Comment: The question only requires the filename, hence the print $9. It assumes no filenames have spaces though.